# Why doesnt this option selector work

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am trying to load a new page (a new div actually using jQuery mobile) depending on what radio button is selected.

```
<div id="main_menu">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <div class="radioOne">
                <input type="radio" name="entry" id="radio-choice-1" value="addEmail" checked="checked" />
                <label for="radio-choice-1" class="boldWhite">Add Email Address</label>
            </div>
            <div id="entry_active_contests">
                Active Contest(s)
            </div>
            <input type="radio" name="entry" id="radio-choice-2" value="contest1"  />
            <label for="radio-choice-2" class="boldWhite">Contest</label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

The script is like

```
$('.choose').click(function(){
    if ($("input[@name='entry']:checked").val() == 'addEmail'){
        window.location.hash ="first";
        alert ('1');
    }
    else if  ($("input[@name='entry']:checked").val() == 'contest1') {
        window.location.hash ="contest";
        alert ('2');
    }   else {
        alert ('3');
    }
});
```

All I ever get is alert 3.  It is extra weird because I made a fiddle and it works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/zkQHP/1/

Any ideas of why this wouldnt work for my actual site?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using on your site?

Comment: Doing this `$("input[@name='entry']:checked").val() ` 2 times is very poor design. Store the value one time and reuse!

Comment: Good thought.. 1.5.min .. i tried the fiddle with 1.5 and it worked fine

Comment: Are you cached? Clear it and retry. Are you sure code/html is 100% same between your code and the jsfiddle code?

Comment: thanks epascarello.. i will rewrite.. and yes it is 100% same

Comment: `console.log(escape($("input[@name='entry']:checked").val())` see any spaces or anything else unexpected in the debug output?

Comment: Thanks I just did that... it is telling me M  is the value ??

Comment: I had to add class="choose" to both Radio buttons from your examples to get it to work. But inside JSfiddle or out it works fine for me.

Comment: `console.log("input[@name='entry']:checked"));` should show you the element, is it some other element on the page?

Comment: it is just showing that exact string input[@name='entry']:checked

Comment: Ahhh thanks I figured it out... I found the conflict.. there was a conflicting class.

Comment: LOL that is exactly what I was saying below in the comment of my answer.  Congrats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/QMw9P/  I agree with epascarello's comment I'd alter the code to read:

```
$('.choose').click(function() {
    var valToCompare = $("input[name='entry']:checked").val();

    if (valToCompare == 'addEmail') {
        window.location.hash = "first";
        alert('1');
    } else if (valToCompare == 'contest1') {
        window.location.hash = "contest";
        alert('2');
    } else {
        alert('3');
    }
});
```

Comment: yes I did that, it makes no difference though I am still having a weird issue where it thinks the value is M no matter what I check

Comment: If this works in the JSFiddle and I did try it locally as well, then the error is coming from outside the info you've provided.  The HTML and javascript you've provided work as intended.

Comment: Epascarello's questions helped me to discover the answer.. it was just a stupid conflict I had with class names.  I will accept yours to close this sucker.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait.. this still doesnt make sense to me.  The other radio has a different name.  Any ideas why `console.log("input[@name='entry']:checked")` would return another input that has the name "gender" in addition to the one I want with name=entry ?

Comment: if you're selecting input[name='entry']:checked I see no way for that to select something with a name=entry.  However, if you're selecting by class when you bind the click you could be entering this code unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this

```
else {
        alert ('3');
    }
```

Why not make it two if statements or an if/else statement?

```
$('.choose').click(function(){

    var val = $("input[@name='entry']:checked").val();

    if(val == 'addEmail'){
        window.location.hash ="first";
        alert ('1');
    }
    if(val == 'contest1') {
        window.location.hash ="contest";
        alert ('2');
    }   
});
```

Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/zkQHP/6/

Answer (score -2):

You can easily grab the selected radio button with `$(':checked')`. I'm not sure why you're jumping through these hoops.

```
$('.choose').click(function(){
    console.log($(':checked').val());
    // You have the selected radio button here
    // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: thanks.. much cleaner.. however it is still returning a value of M.  I have no idea where it is getting that

Comment: And what if the person has more radio buttons on the page?

Comment: This doesn't work if there are other radio buttons on the page with class="choose".